# pentaho report excel output - leading '0' gets truncated

Tags: excel, reporting, pentaho, trim

I have a format issue with my pentaho report excel/csv output.

My report output contains zip code column, which has leading zeroes if the zip code length is less than 5. the leading zeroes get truncated when i open the report output in excel file. I used 'textfield' for the zipcode column, i even tried concatenating zeroes in my xaction sql. everything works fine if i open the output in a text editor, but when we open it in excel file the zero got trimmed.

can we prevent this trimming issue  or can we use other data fields in design instead of text field.

Comment: yes i tried but prefixing single quotes, but the single quote appears on other output formats.

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension of your csv to .txt so you get Excel's dialogue boxes for importing text files; there you can select the comma as your column delimiter. On the third screen (after you hit "next" twice), there is an option to choose the formatting of each column. Select you zip code column, change it from "General" to "Text" format, and your leading zeroes will be retained.

Comment: Hi proofreader thq for your reply, but the problem is my client is using the report, and i cant ask them to open the output and format it. i just want to is there any way to prevent the leading zero truncation in pentaho itself.

Answer (score 0):

use text formatting in the Home-->Number-->Special
Cannt paste imapge--> i guess not enough points

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is proper or not but enclose field in Double quotes or single which ever you prefer..
quotes will not display in excel file format but it will display in textpad or notepad..
So it you don't have any problem in adding this extra thing then it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the original data format in your DB? Is it an INT?
In your sql statement, try something like this (adjust for the relevant sql dialect, if necessary):

```
lpad(cast(zip as CHAR(5)),5,'0') zip
```

where `zip` is your field name.
Then use text-field as you are already doing.